# Access problems. Why can't I access some of my private requests?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm testing LMS API using https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/

I have:
App ID
App Key
User ID
User Key

I can get users from my LMS API https://lms.freedomhighschool.ca/d2l/api/lp/1.30/users/
This is private route and i have access to it.

But when i'm trying to create new user i got "Message": "Not Authorized"

This is admin user and i can login via LMS and to do everything i want(create, delete, update) users.

So, what's the problem? Why can't i create new user via https://apitesttool.desire2learnvalence.com/ ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE98j.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmOiC.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have RoleId = 0. In order to create a Brightspace User, you need to provide a Role Id value.

The user account you are using in the Test Tool will also need to have the appropriate permissions to Enroll users. For example, if you are wanting to enroll a "Student" then your user account needs to have the permission "Users - Enroll 'Student'" turned ON.

Comment: Also, have you considered using OAuth2+Postman instead of the (old) ID-Key-Auth+APITestTool?
https://github.com/Brightspace/Postman-Collections

Comment: Yes thank you. I noticed that I cannot create all users. But only those whose role is: leaner, teacher. For now, that's enough for me

Comment: We are using gem 'd2l-valence' for our rails application. As i understand it use APITestTool